# Odd pattern in Java bytecode

Tags: java, bytecode, decompiling

I've been looking at some Java bytecode, and I keep finding an odd pattern in it that I can't seem to translate into any reasonable Java construct:

```
    if ( <cond1> )
        goto Label;

    do {
        <code1>
Label:
        <code2>
    } while ( <cond2> );
```

Is there any reasonable Java construct that this can be decompiled to? All I can think of is very complicated patterns which introduce extra state to keep track of whether it is the first iteration of the loop or not.

Comment: Do you know what created this bytecode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (init condition for which cond2 reduces to cond1; cond2; code1) {
  code2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have picked out that it's a for-loop pattern. I can see now that the code1 is obviously the increment code.